# Getting data from calendar on Android Wear

Tags: java, android, wear-os, android-calendar

**I'm querying the calendar data like this:**

```
// Constructor of the class
mCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, mColumns, null, null, null);
updateEvents();

//contents of updateEvents:
events.clear();
mCursor.moveToFirst();
mLastUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (!mCursor.isAfterLast())
{
    long end = mCursor.getLong(2);
    if (end > mLastUpdate)
        events.add(new Event(mCursor));

    mCursor.moveToNext();
}
```

The code manages works on mobile device, however when it's run on a Wear device there appears to be no data.

I've found a `WaerableCalendarContract`, but it doesn't seem to contain the `Events` class that I use to fill the mColumns class to select the desired data.

How can I do the same on the Wear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WearableCalendarContract` describes a 24 hour long window (starting from the current time) of calendar data. You don't see Event there, because we transfer [`Instances`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Instances.html) objects. As you can see in base interface for `Instances`, it does include `Events` columns too, so you should be able to fetch the data that you need from there.

If you need more than 24 hours of data, you will need sync it yourself. Query the calendar on the phone and then for each event that interests you, construct a `DataItem`. This is a little tricky, so I would recommend using the WearableCalendarContract instead.

Comment: so I assume `WearableCalendarContract` is synced automatically all the time?

Comment: Yes, whenever the calendar changes, we will sync the data. The exception are attendees, which will be throttled to once per hour.

Comment: Hi! Would you be able to point me to a sample app which shows how to use WearableCalendarContract? When I try to use the above contract on wearOS emulator, the contract keeps returning 0 values.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't worked on Android Wear for many years :( You will need to look into the official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to sync your data to the Wear app manually, a.k.a fetch it from the `ContentProvider` on the phone and then send it to the `wearable` via the `DataItem API`. Read more about syncing data between phone<->wear [HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html).